# Does FB Graph api v2.5 still support Manage_notifications in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am trying to access facebook notifications using FB graph api v 2.5 but I am having error of code: 200 requires extended permission.

for this I am using manage_notifications for taking permissions, which is deprecated in v2.5.

Is manage_notifications supported in v2.5 ?

How to get facebook notications using graph api or facebook sdk 3.5 in android?

Comment: as it is deprecated in v 2.4 you can not use it any more. Try to contact facebook about this issue...